# How to destroy child object when parent is destroyed?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm  making a 2D game in Unity 5 in which the player has a gun which is child to the player, how can I destroy the gun when the player is hit ? The current code I'm using destroys the player but not the gun.

```
public float health=500f;
public GameObject gun;

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider){
    BulletScript bullet = collider.gameObject.GetComponent<BulletScript> ();

    if (bullet) {
        health -= bullet.getdamage ();
        bullet.hit ();
        Handheld.Vibrate();

        if (health <= 0) {
            GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("deadBool", true);
            GetComponent<Animator> ().SetTrigger ("deadTrigger");
            ExecuteAfterTime (1f);
            Destroy (gun);
        }
    }

}
IEnumerator ExecuteAfterTime(float time){
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (time);
    Destroy (gameObject);
    GameObject child = gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<> (gameObject);
}
```

Note: The gun is the child of the player on which the script is applied.

Comment: I assume the gun is automaticaly garbage-collected when no more references to it exist. So when your player dies the reference-counter decreases by one. If you don´t have any further references to that gun it´ll be thrown away soon. Anyway: why not call `Destroy(child)`?

Comment: Child Object *should* automatically destroy when its parent is destroyed. Please do a simple test with a GameObject and a child then just destroy the parent. The child should be gone too.

Comment: The gun must be a child of player on Hierarchy view to be destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to destroy every child you can first of all retrieve all the children with :

```
allChildren  = gameObject.getComponentsInChildren()
```

this will result in an array, so after you can simply iterate through them with a loop like:

```
for (int a = 0; a < allChildren.length; aa ++)
{
    Destroy(allChildren[a].gameObject);
}
```

if the gun is the only child you want to destroy inside that loop you can query for details about the object and call Destroy when you find the gun, something like:

```
if(allChildren[a].name == "gun")
{
    Destroy(allChildren[a].gameObject)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to destroy only the gun, then I would say keep a reference of your gun in the script like this:

```
public GameObject gun;
```

Assign the gun from inspector. Then just destroy it when hit like this:

```
Destroy(gun);
```

If you have multiple children under player. Then you can create an array like this:

```
public GameObject[] destroyables;
```

Assign it from inspector and save the prefab. Then use a loop to destroy when hit.

```
for(int i=0;i<destroyables.Length;i++) Destroy(destroyables[i]);
```

Comment: I have made the changes as you said and my gun is also being destroyed but the only problem is the gun destroys before the player get destroyed having an awkward delay.(I have update the code)

Comment: when do you want to destroy the gun? After the player is destroyed or with the player?

Comment: with the player

Comment: Yo can try to SetActive(false) before destroying anything yo be sure it disappear in the order you like.

Comment: @Varun Call Destroy(gun); before the line Destroy (gameObject);

Comment: I have already tried this but this code is not destroying gun, it is destroying the player but not the gun even the Destroy(gun); is used before the Destroy(gameObject);

Answer (score 0):

When you destroy parent gameObject, all children will destroy automatically. But you try to destroy all of they manually.
You have Delay because you call Destory(gameObject) in coroutine. Try to move Destroy(gun) to the coroutine too.

```
public float health=500f;
public GameObject gun;

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider){
BulletScript bullet = collider.gameObject.GetComponent<BulletScript> ();

    if (bullet) {
        health -= bullet.getdamage ();
        bullet.hit ();
        Handheld.Vibrate();

        if (health <= 0) {
            GetComponent<Animator> ().SetBool ("deadBool", true);
            GetComponent<Animator> ().SetTrigger ("deadTrigger");
            StartCoroutine(ExecuteAfterTime (1f));             
        }
    }

}
IEnumerator ExecuteAfterTime(float time){
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (time);

    //destroying gun only
    Destroy (gun);

    //manually destroying all of childre
    GameObject child = gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<> (gameObject);
    foreach(var entry in child )
    {
        Destroy(entry);
    }

    Destroy (gameObject);

}
```

Comment: Using Destroy(gun); in ExecuteAfterTime() method is not working. Its not destroying the gun.

Comment: You may use ExecuteAfterTime() with StartCoroutine().
I am edit the answer edited.